# Software/library to create artistic plan view of a floorplan

Tags: software-recommendation, resource-recommendations

I'm looking either for a software or for a clipart library to create a top down plan view of a flat. But that should not be simply schematic, but actually look nice with shading and color and so on.

Something like this:
[image: example]

It could be actually even more detailed with nice textures and so on.

Anyone can recommend a dedicated software or clipart library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be all that proper answer. Surely it doesn't answer your question, but I think this could pass.

---

At least if you are looking to do this based on existing funiture and apartment, which you are not specific about.

If you want premade images of furniture and other objects, problem is that we don't live in a society where people live in identical houses. So, the odds of you finding completely identical sofa, table, lamp, bed and most of the stuff...are very slim. Especially when we are talking about illustration of these objects which would also have to have about the same style.

---

If it's just imaginary setup, then I take it back.

So I felt bad not answering the actual question and googled around for "Interior design software" and who would've guessed autodesk had something just like that.. :)

http://www.homestyler.com/designer

http://www.homestyler.com/gallery

Comment: this is good! exactly what i was looking for :) yes - it's for a imaginary setup! thank you!

Comment: i never knew homestyler existed! this is going to be amazing for future school projects

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how pricky you want to be with the design of the house.

For our university projects we sometimes need to show a generic floor plan: when the plan is only indicative, an image search in google often finds something adequate in a matter of seconds;

However if the actual design floor plan is at all important, we often find it easier/faster make a quick 3d model in [Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/) (free). With the 3d warehouse you can populate the model with furniture quite fast and you can give your plan a nice slight 3d effect. Its proper CAD software though, so although its reasonably powerful it does have a slight learning curve if your not used to CAD.